# zsh: no matches found: --pallet=*

Tags: substrate-node-template

Getting `zsh: no matches found: --pallet=*` while running substrate chain benchmarks.

My command-

```
./target/production/node-template benchmark pallet --chain dev --execution=wasm --wasm-execution=compiled --pallet=* --extrinsic=* --steps 50 --repeat 20 --output pallets/all-weight.rs
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to escape `*` with `\`. So the above command looks like this -

```
./target/production/node-template benchmark pallet --chain dev --execution=wasm --wasm-execution=compiled --pallet=\* --extrinsic=\* --steps 50 --repeat 20 --output pallets/all-weight.rs
```

More info about this issue [here](https://%20%20%20%20./target/production/node-template%20benchmark%20pallet%20--chain%20dev%20--execution=wasm%20--wasm-execution=compiled%20--pallet=*%20--extrinsic=*%20--steps%2050%20--repeat%2020%20--output%20pallets/all-weight.rs)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue in Unix CLI I think.

Use `\*` or `'*'`.